# Very simple menu in XNA

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

Me and some other guys are creating a game, and i would like to add a very simple menu with only Start and Exit Game. Now I already downloaded the Game state management sample, but thats a very long and complicated code. My question: someone knows a site or something where i can make such a simple menu or someone created such a menu by himself and wants to help me.

Im working in Xna4.0.

Edit: A Titlescreen with "press enter to start the game" or something like that would be nice too.

Comment: What platform(s) (and therefore input methods) will you be targeting?

Comment: you can watch this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=54L_w0PiRa8&feature=BFa&list=PL667AC2BF84D85779

Answer (score 5):

The Game State Management sample is not long or complicated.

My recommendation is to make your way through it until you understand how they implemented the menu system, which is close to the most basic menu that you can have, while maintaining the minimum functionality of what a menu should do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a tutorial currently walking you through building a menu, but I do have one covering screen states (this is what you would use to get your "Press Enter to Start" screen).

You can read through that tutorial here -> http://www.xnadevelopment.com/tutorials/thestateofthings/thestateofthings.shtml

I wrote the tutorial to ease people into understanding the Game State Management tutorial on the creator's site so hopefully it's helpful in getting you to understand the concepts.