# How to add a start (splash) screen in XNA 4.0?

Tags: xna-4.0

I just want to create a simple splash screen containing the following in the menu;

" Press "Enter" to start " //
      "Instructions"

(obviously when you're in the instructions page, there should be a "click here to return back to main menu option"

The game I'm creating is a 2D Racing Game (I haven't implemented timing in that (dno how to))

I've tried to implement this in my code;
http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/game_state_management

But I gave up after half an hours (too complicated)

Any help is welcome. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 3):

Another course of action you could take is using enum's to store different game states.

```
//Don't forget to put this above the Game1 class!
public enum GameState
{
    Menu,
    Game, 
    Credits,
    Etc
}
```

Initialize it:

```
GameState gameState = new GameState();
gameState = GameState.Menu;
```

Then in you're draw method:

```
if(gameState == GameState.Menu)
{
// Draw your menu, do other stuff for other gamestates.
}
```

Finally in the update:

```
if(gameState == GameState.Menu)
{
// check if keyboard is pressed and continue if it is
}
else if(gameState == GameState.Game)
{
// Your main game update logic
}
```

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track with the Microsoft Game State Management example. Essentially you need state management of some sort to control what shows and when.

This could be as simple as having an enum flag that changes the game objects (textures etc) in your main Draw method -- ["Press Enter to start the game" XNA INTRO SCREEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952855/press-enter-to-start-the-game-xna-intro-screen)

Check out the Catapult Wars lab ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg266460 ) for an implementation of the GSM example which is a MUCH more robust solution.