# XNA Screen Management

Tags: c#, xna

im using this example from the AppHub http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/game_state_management
Im using this example to create a menu system for my game. The game is already created and working without any sort of Menu's etc hence why i wish to use the game state management.

I have been looking at the example and it only really says to implement the game code into the GameplayScreen class. However I have problems with this as I cant then load certain game elements at this location for several reasons (One being that this class doesnt inherit the Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game) So im a bit of a loss how i can load them somewhere else for example and get access to them still. My Game is made up of two pieces primarily, PongSystem Which controls most of the game and PongGame which holds most of the nitty gritty of the game.

If someone could help by explaining how i can implement my game into this example the easiest way that would be appreciated. 
My game can be found here - http://min.us/mYZYMgzdC

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind a basic `winform` menu you can always create a menu in windows form and call your game with the `Process` class.

```
        Process myProcess = new Process();
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = //You .exe FilePath
        myProcess.Start();
```

If you don't like this approach, someone posted a question like yours [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941418/very-simple-menu-in-xna) and got a few links.

Good luck with your menu.

Comment: Thanks very much will have a look through that now :)

Comment: No problem don,t hesitate if you have any questions:)

Answer (score 0):

Using GameComponent objects you can load everything you need.(  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gamecomponent.aspx )  They are threaded and ideal for handling different sections of logic without cluttering your screens.

Create a main screen and add components to it, then create your main game class and it can refereence your comoponents.

Sorry If I am not explaining this very clearly.

Answer (score 0):

From my past projects, I have found that these tutorials (1-7) are very helpful on using GSM,

first part - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-mw6kGYCllI

last part - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3fbCZMuPCe0

It will give you a nice base which you can build upon if you follow the tutorials.

Heres a screenshot the latest game menu/game i developed.

http://philipstarritt.com/wave/ironfist

Hope this helps